# R - Subset of rows in Date Format

Tags: r, subset

I Have a DF with daily prices of an ETF like this:

```
             TICKER  OPEN     HIGH   CLOSE  
2017-01-01   BOVA11  55.30    55.50  55.20
```

My rows names are assigned as dates (YYMMDD), how can I use basic R commands to subset this data frame from rows 2017-01-01 to 2017-01-31?

Thanks

Comment: See `?Date` -- dates should be encoded using a numerical format instead of string row names. However, I guess you can use `DF[rownames(DF) >= "2017-01-01" & yada_yada, ]`

Comment: Thanks! As you said, I guess I should put the dates in columns again. I was doing to keep the data similar to quantmod function getSymbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that `DF` is actually an `xts` object.  If that is the case, you can refer to a date range using a string which consists of the start and end date, separated by a forward slash (`/`):

```
jan2017_data = DF["2017-01-01/2017-01-31"]
```

Answer (score 0):

They all begin with 2017-01 so just grep on that:

```
DF[grep("2017-01", rownames(DF)), ]
```

which for the input in the Note below gives:

```
           TICKER OPEN HIGH CLOSE
2017-01-01 BOVA11 55.3 55.5  55.2
2017-01-15 BOVA11 55.3 55.5  55.2
2017-01-31 BOVA11 55.3 55.5  55.2
```

**Note:** The input `DF` shown in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
             TICKER  OPEN     HIGH   CLOSE  
2017-01-01   BOVA11  55.30    55.50  55.20
2017-01-15   BOVA11  55.30    55.50  55.20
2017-01-31   BOVA11  55.30    55.50  55.20
2017-02-01   BOVA11  55.30    55.50  55.20"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```